# how to replace empty tag from output xml file using for-each loop in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input xml:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>

     461

   </sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>

     70

   </sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>

     461

  </sb:first-page>

</sb:pages>
```

my output xml:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>70</sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page/>

</sb:pages>
```

i dont want second last-page in my output xml. because sb:pages[last()]/sb:last-page is not in my input xml.
i am using for-each loop in my xslt. what i have to do to get the output xml without empty tag?

My expected output xml is:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>70</sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

</sb:pages>
```

Comment: Could you post your current XSL? (And remove the empty lines from your XML files to make the XML sections more concise and easier to read?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd" version='2.0'>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="sb:last-page">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.)!=''">
               <xsl:element name="sb:last-page"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```